# Forms affect other forms and submit button Disable/enable

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I should compose a page which there is more packages.
Firstly; visitors have to select  person number, after selection Start button will enable and when visitor push button redirect to form4.html with get method.
When I put 3 Forms  all forms affect the others. 
Please Help Me

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title></title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
 <!----Drop Down And Submit - Start-----> 
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {

//Start Buttons
    $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });
    
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        if ($('.dropdown').val() == 0) {
          $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: true });
        } else {
          $(".nextbutton").button({ disabled: false });
        }
    });

});
});//]]>  
</script>
 <!----Drop Down And Submit - End----->
         <script type="text/javascript">
        function submitform()
        {
            document.forms["drop_list"].submit();
        }
        </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  
       
<h3>PACKAGE - 1 </h3>
       <form name="drop_list" action="../../form/form4.html" method="get" class="j-forms j-multistep">
<form name="drop_list" action="../../form/form4.html" method="get" class="j-forms j-multistep">
 <select name="select" class="dropdown">
   <option value=''>Person Number</option>
            <option value="Person-1">1</option>
            <option value="Person-2">2</option>
            <option value="Person-3">3</option>
            <option value="Person-4">4</option>
            <option value="Person-5">5</option>
            <option value="Person-6">6</option>
            <option value="Person-7">7</option>
            <option value="Person-8">8</option>
            <option value="Person-9">9</option>
           </select><br><br>

    <input class="nextbutton" value="Start" type="button" onClick="submitform()"></form>
       
 <br>_____________________________________________________________________<br>
   
       
<h3>PACKAGE - 2 </h3>
<form name="drop_list" action="../../form/form4.html" method="get" class="j-forms j-multistep">
 <select name="select" class="dropdown">
   <option value=''>Person Number</option>
            <option value="Person-1">1</option>
            <option value="Person-2">2</option>
            <option value="Person-3">3</option>
            <option value="Person-4">4</option>
            <option value="Person-5">5</option>
            <option value="Person-6">6</option>
            <option value="Person-7">7</option>
            <option value="Person-8">8</option>
            <option value="Person-9">9</option>
           </select><br><br>

    <input class="nextbutton" value="Start" type="button" onClick="submitform()"></form>
    
<br>_____________________________________________________________________<br>
   
     
<h3>PACKAGE - 3 </h3>
 <form name="drop_list" action="../../form/form4.html" method="get" class="j-forms j-multistep">
 <select name="select" class="dropdown">
   <option value=''>Person Number</option>
            <option value="Person-1">1</option>
            <option value="Person-2">2</option>
            <option value="Person-3">3</option>
            <option value="Person-4">4</option>
            <option value="Person-5">5</option>
            <option value="Person-6">6</option>
            <option value="Person-7">7</option>
            <option value="Person-8">8</option>
            <option value="Person-9">9</option>
           </select><br><br>

    <input class="nextbutton" value="Start" type="button" onClick="submitform()"></form>
       
    

 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm confused...are you trying to have each button hit a different controller?

Comment: Your first form-element is not closed.

Comment: In your *change*-function you set the *disabled*-property to false on all elements in the document, if the value of the drop down is not zero.

Comment: Hi @uUuR If you found an answer that helped you, you can mark that answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Like i said in the comment to your question, one of your problems is that you actually change all the buttons of class *.nextbutton* at once.

You could change your change-function to

```
  $('.dropdown').change(function() {
    $(this.form).find('.nextbutton').button({ disabled: this.value === '' });
  });
```

What is does is using *this* that is the element that triggered the function. By using *this.form* I get the form of that element. And with that I only change the button on the current form.

I also got rid of the *if*-statement, because that was a Boolean expression, and the *disabled*-property is also a Boolean.